# Tensorflow autoencoder attempt: ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer`

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder, encoder

I am encountering the following error while trying to write an encoder model for a variational autoencoder:

```
ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: [[-0.02135764 -0.01809833  0.00880998 ... -0.02307652  0.00028993 0.00441882]...
```

Below is a simplified version of my code. The issue appears to be coming from the type of x, which is apparently  `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`.

```
def encoder(inputs, latent_dim):

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 248, 40, 1), name="input_layer")
x = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3, 0))(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (9, 1), strides=(5, 1), batch_size=batch_size)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(encoder_inputs, x, name="encoder")
return model
```

I have tried creating the model with output `x.output` instead of simply `x`, but EagerTensors have no such attribute. :(
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Some additional code to provide more context. I'm calling the function as follows, where X_train is a 20x248x40x1 numpy array (20  inputs of shape 248x40x1).

```
model1 = encoder(X_train, 100)
```

Comment: You need to make a complete example that reproduces the problem, not a simplified one.

Comment: You should probably decide whether you want to use `inputs` or `encoder_inputs`, your current code mixes them in a really weird way and this is not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

`encoder_inputs`

on the first line like here:

```
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
processed = keras.layers.RandomCrop(width=32, height=32)(encoder_inputs)
conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=3)(processed)
pooling = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(conv)
feature = keras.layers.Dense(10)(pooling)

full_model = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, feature)
backbone = keras.Model(processed, conv)
activations = keras.Model(conv, feature)
```

Or more specific it is about what you are trying to do ... you want an model that does the computation so create the model than add stuff to it. So i define your encoder and its layer structure

```
def encoder():

  encoder_inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 248, 40, 1), 
                                  name="input_layer")
  x = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(3, 0))(encoder_inputs)
  x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (9, 1), strides=(5, 1), 
  batch_size=batch_size)(x)

  model = tf.keras.Model(encoder_inputs, x, name="encoder")
  return model
```

then inputs is used later like here, for example to minimize the Mean square error between your inputs and some targets with the encoder model:

```
  inputs = your_inputs
  targets = yout targets
  model = encoder()
  model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse", metrics=["mae", "acc"])
  model.fit(inputs,targets)
```

More info can be found at [tf.keras.Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

Comment: Thank you so much! Although I did find that the code only worked when I wrote model = Model(inputs=encoder_inputs...), is there a reason I should use inputs instead?

Comment: I edited my answer so it gives some more info on the issue. You fiurst define a model then compile and then feed it with tensors or numpy arrays. You just wanted to feed the inputs in the model defintion without compiling the model.